# Threading start for function return assigned to multiple variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have function called generic_df_filter which return a data frame for which I have two assignment

```
df_mkpi = mean_kpi = generic_df_filter(arg1,arg2)
```

I want to run this in multithreading so I try this .

```
from threading import Thread
df_mkpi = mean_kpi = Thread(target=generic_df_filter , args = (arg1,arg2))
```

My doubt is that Do I need to start two thread  like this

```
df_mkpi.start() ; mean_kpi.start()
```

Or staring one thread will be good enough as shown below.

```
df_mkpi.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created 2 individuals threads objects. If you want to start only one thread you need the `start()` command so if you want to start only one thread `df_mkpi.start()` or `mean_kpi.start()` if you want to start two individual threads `df_mkpi.start() ; mean_kpi.start()`
or

```
df_mkpi.start() 
mean_kpi.start()
```

Comment: since both df_mkpi & mean_kpi is same . is there any elegant way of starting one thread and assign to another without starting second one ?

Comment: I dont understand exactly your question but i assume you want to do this df_mkpi = mean_kpi = Thread(target=generic_df_filter , args = (arg1,arg2)) and after that start only the desire thread with start command anywhere you like in your programm

Comment: df_mkpi =  Thread (<code>) ; mean_kpi = df_mkpi.start() . Can this be done?

Comment: I think not. but you can do df_mkpi = Thread (<code>) ; mean_kpi = df_mkpi; mean_kpi.start(); df_mkpi.start()